# Remove unwanted columns from included tables EF Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have this query:

```
IQueryable<CategoryEntity> i = _dbContext.Set<CategoryEntity>()
        .Where(x => x.DeletedAt == null)
        .Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
        .Include(i => i.Media)
        .Include(i => i.Children.Where(x => x.DeletedAt == null)).ThenInclude(i => i.Media).Where(i => i.DeletedAt == null)
        .AsNoTracking();

return new GenericResponse<IQueryable<CategoryEntity>>(i);
```

In this query I have so many fields in `Media` and `Category` entities that I don't want to return from database so the query would be as efficient as possible. I tried using a `select` but I got every kinds of errors.

What is the most efficient way to query a database with multiple includes in EF Core?

Comment: Use `select`. Only option. Show the errors if you need more help on that.

Comment: Why do you use `Include(i => i.Media)` when you actually don't want the `Media` entity?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most efficient way to query a database with multiple includes in EF Core?

Don't use includes, just select the columns you need.

If you need complete entity instances - eg. to make use of change tracking - you do need to get the complete entity, but otherwise you don't. Eg.

```
from o in db.Orders
where o.Id = theOrderId
select new {
  o.Id,
  o.Status,
  Items = o.OrderItems
}
```

will get just two columns from the matching order row, but the complete `OrderItem` entities (thus having change tracking).

(Suggestion: if you have the option, design your schema so entities you need changing tracking on avoid overheads; move other data into a second entity that you only load when needed. This is particularly beneficial when dealing with BLOB/CLOB columns.)